# disabling the cocos2d-x left down corner texts

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

In all codes I've written with cocos2d-x there is a part in the screen at left down corner. It has 3 lines. I've found that the first line is for counting nodes in the scene. What exactly it is and how can I remove it from the screen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the 3rd line is the FPS. for disabling this part, Go to `AppDelegate.cpp` file , then go to the function: `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and delete or comment this line:

```
pDirector->setDisplayStats(true);
```

OR, set the input value to `false`

Answer (score 0):

Go into`AppDelegate.m` file in your project. In the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, change

```
[director_ setDisplayStats:YES];
```

to

```
[director_ setDisplayStats:NO];
```